# ActiveRecord: Accessing owner association after building record

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, associations

Using Rails 2.3.14, I'm looking for way to access the owner of an ActiveRecord object after it was build (but before save) to get some values from the owner. Seems to be simple, but my approach always fires an unnecessary database query.

Example:

```
class Parent < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :children
end

class Child < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :parent

  def after_initialize
    self.some_value = parent.some_value
    # This fires an additional database query to get the parent
  end
end

parent = Parent.find(1)
# SELECT * FROM `parents` WHERE (`parents`.`id` = 1) 

child = parent.children.build
# Same SELECT query is fired again, but of course not needed
```

I'm looking for a way to access the association object (here: parent) **without** doing an additional database access. How can this be done?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Rails 3, there's a new option, :inverse_of, for belongs_to/has_many to do this, but not in Rails 2. Maybe you have to implement similar function by yourself.

Comment: Great, this is exactly what I'm looking for.

BTW, `inverse_of` **does** exists in Rails 2.3, see the Changelog: https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/2-3-stable/activerecord/CHANGELOG